# How important are records of fraudulent applications?

Tags: credit, fraud, identity-theft, record-keeping

How important is it to try to get copies of the fraudulent applications/materials used by the thieves?  This appears to be a [consumer right according to the FTC](http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0233-statement-rights-identity-theft-victims#Communicating), but the companies seem not to want to provide it and can deny giving this info to the victim in some cases (for this Experien references [this government site with links](http://www.consumerfinance.gov/learnmore) in a letter).  I'm wondering if this is worth all the back-and-forth with the fraud departments of the companies or if this kind of information is much less important than just taking precautions, filing police reports, credit monitoring, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason for you to ask for it is so that you could forward it to law enforcement if for some reason they cannot get it on their own. You may be able to identify the thief if it is someone you know (recognize the hand writing, style, address, phone, etc) and report to the detective handling your case. Other than that - not much use to you.

Comment: @stackuser - I would want any paperwork available so I could recreate the entire case from scratch.  My motivation is based on the admittedly minor possibility of crossing the law some years later AND the law doesn't believe your history. Better safe than sorry, and I simply wouldn't trust any gov't to keep track of my records.  (I believe they would honestly try but mistakes happen.)